# Angular: refactor cases of a switch statement to components without changing the resulting DOM

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular9

I am trying to swap out the different cases of a switch statement into components without changing the resulting DOM tree.

## Example

I made an [example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chqyws).

As a basis I used the example [Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) from the angular.io guide.

The Component i want to refactor is *DynamicFormQuestion*.
The goal is to introduce a new component per question controlType (*QuestionDropdownComponent*, *QuestionTextBoxComponent*) without changes to the resulting DOM. 
**DynamicFormQuestionComponent** should still be used as a component for a question of any type.

**Original** *dynamic-form-question.component.html*:

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>

  <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">

    <input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [formControlName]="question.key"
            [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type">

    <select [id]="question.key" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [formControlName]="question.key">
      <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
    </select>

  </div>

  <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{question.label}} is required</div>
</div>
```

### New templates

*dynamic-form-question.component.html*:

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">
    <app-question-textbox *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [question]="question" [form]="form"></app-question-textbox>
    <app-question-dropdown *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [question]="question" [form]="form"></app-question-dropdown>
</ng-container>
```

*question-textbox.component.html*:

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>
  <input [formControlName]="question.key" [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type">
  <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{question.label}} is required</div>
</div>
```

*question-dropdown.component.html*:

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>
    <select [id]="question.key" [formControlName]="question.key">
      <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
  </select>
    <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{question.label}} is required</div>
</div>
```

This Example works, but the resulting DOM Tree contains the unwanted elements `<app-question-textbox>` and `<app-question-dropdown>`.

What is the best solution to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the help of **attribute selector** but a single div is required. Can be done as below:

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">
    <div app-question-textbox *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [question]="question" [form]="form"></div>
    <div app-question-dropdown *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [question]="question" [form]="form"></div>
</ng-container>
```

Rest will be same.

Comment: This solution will introduce an additional div into DOM tree. I asked for a solution that leaves the DOM unchanged.

Comment: I know I mentioned that in first line. Other than that this is not possible.